# JavaScript Regex - add ~ symbol between lettes except letter after space

Tags: javascript, regex

how can I put ~ symbol between letters except the first letter after space? Here is what I got from this site by trying here and there.

```
txt = text.split(/ +?/g).join(" ");
txt.replace(/(.)(?=.)/g, "$1~")
```

this regex output as

```
input = "hello friend"
output = "h~e~l~l~o~ ~f~r~i~e~n~d"
```

How to output `"h~e~l~l~o~ f~r~i~e~n~d"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\S` instead of `.` when matching the character you want to insert a `~` next to - `\S` matches any non-space character, whereas `.` matches any non-newline character.

```js
const text = 'hello friend';
const singleSpaced = text.split(/ +/g).join(" ");
const output = singleSpaced.replace(/(\S)(?=.)/g, "$1~");
console.log(output);
```

or

```js
const text = 'hello friend';
const output = text
  .replace(/ +/g, ' ')
  .replace(/(\S)(?=.)/g, "$1~");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one operation with a [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) using this regex:

```
(?<=\S)(?!$)
```

It matches the position after a non-whitespace character `(?<=\S)` except for the position at end of string `(?!$)`. You can then insert a `~` at those positions:

```js
text = "hello friend"
txt = text.replace(/(?<=\S)(?!$)/g, '~') 

console.log(txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match a single non whitespace char, and assert that to the right is not optional whitespace chars followed by the end of the string.

In the replacement use the full match followed by a tilde `$&~`

```
\S(?!\s*$)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8dnKf8/1).

```js
input = "hello friend"
output = input.replace(/\S(?!\s*$)/g, '$&~') 

console.log(output)
```